# Google app engine bot attack?

Tags: security, google-app-engine

I have an application in Google app engine that only runs cron jobs and uses a backend, so there are no incoming requests from any client. I noticed that a request from a user named 'niki-bot' was received and I'm quite surprised as my app url does not appear anywhere it's only used by admin account which sends cron requests. Fortunately I had setup security on my crons so this user got a 403 forbidden message, but I'm still wondering how could this happen. Has any of you guys experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you are aware, backends are [addressable to the outside world](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Addressing_backends), it's only the [public/private status](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Public_and_private_backends) and the security level applied to the endpoints that determines if the calls are successful.

Regarding how a bot would have gotten your App ID, I suppose they could just be trying random ones to see if there is anything they can exploit.

Were the requests for standard admin endpoints? I get many random requests for the PHP files below, and my app isn't even on PHP. People just trying to attack known systems (this is on my front-end module):

```
/mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php
/myadmin/scripts/setup.php
/MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php
/pma/scripts/setup.php
/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php
/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php
/db/scripts/setup.php
/dbadmin/scripts/setup.php
```

Answer (score 3):

You were likely running the 'Awesome Screenshot' plugin in your browser, or similar software which leaks all your browsing history to an upstream service - that upstream service appears to return with a niki-bot crawler to scrape or do something with those 'impossible to otherwise find' URLs.

Read more about it here: https://mig5.net/content/awesome-screenshot-and-niki-bot